# I have a DataFrame with some values of np.inf. How does .corr() work?

Tags: python, pandas

What will happen when I use df.corr()?  Will np.inf effect my results some how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

np.inf is treated the same way np.NaN.

I replaced the all the values of np.inf with np.NaN and the results were exactly the same.  If there is some subtle differences, please let me know.  I was looking for an answer on this and couldn't find one anywhere so I figured I would post this here.